DDD: Can an Entity be also an Aggregate?
I'm approaching DDD and I'm in trouble with a (very common, I suppose...) use case where a hierarchy of related objects is involved.
Let's imagine modeling a Software Product made of many Modules bundled together:

Scenario 1: The Aggregate is the Entity itself

// The 'Product' entity
class Product {
    
   String version;      // Identity
   Set<Module> modules; // Entities
   Date releasedOn;     // VO
   Author releasedBy;   // VO
   ...
   ...

}

// The 'Module' Entity
class Module {
  
   ModuleVersion version;   // Identity
   String name;
   ModuleMetadata metadata; // VO
   ...

}


At the first moment, I identified the "Product" class as an Entity because, in my context, it has an identity (the version).
But the "Product" class is always an aggregation of other objects because it is the parent in a composition tree.

Is it correct to say that, under some circumstances, an entity also acts as an Aggregate?
If yes, is it correct to say that, in this case, the entity that acts as Aggregate is the Aggregate root itself?

Scenario 2: Introducing a physical Class to model the Aggregate acting as a simple Wrapper
Another way of modeling the scenario would be the implementation of the "ProductAggregate" to "physically" model the Aggregate, but honestly I can't see which benefit it can bring to:

// The 'Product' aggregate. 
// Which benefit of introducing this wrapper?
class ProductAggregate {
    
   Product product; 

}

// The 'Product' entity
class Product {
    
   String version;      // Identity
   Set<Module> modules; // Entities
   Date releasedOn;     // VO
   Author releasedBy;   // VO
   ...

}

...


Scenario 3: Introducing a physical Class to model the Aggregate moving  "Modules" to the Aggregate
// The 'Product' aggregate
class ProductAggregate {
    
   Product product;
   Set<Module> modules;
   ...

}

// The 'Product' entity (without modules)
class Product {
    
   String version;      // Identity
   Date releasedOn;     // VO
   Author releasedBy;   // VO
   ...

}

In such cases, the "ProductAggregate" class makes sense and the overall model seems to better adhere to the DDD principles. Anyway to my way of thinking about the real world, using the composition of Case 2 is less natural than using the composition of Case 1.
Any suggestion on which modeling strategy is better to use?
Thank you

in your case the product entity is your aggregate.

In short
Let's look at the definitions by Eric Ewans:

ENTITY: An object fundamentally defined not by its attributes, but by a thread of continuity and identity.
AGGREGATE: A cluster of associated objects that are treated as a unit for the purpose of data changes. External references are restricted to one member of the AGGREGATE, designated as the root. A set of consistency rules applies within the AGGREGATE’S boundaries.

An aggregate can be as simple as a cluster of a single entity, with is then the aggregate root. In such a case, theoretically the aggregate is different of the entity: the aggregate is a cluster that contains a single entity, and that entity is an element of this cluster.  But in practice the two are the same thing in our mind, and therefore most often share the same name. So the answer is sort of pragmatic yes.
Some more thoughts about your specific case
The UML "composite aggregation" (black diamond, colloquially called "composition") in your diagrams tells according to the UML specifications, that the Module's lifecycle is controlled by the Product.  This would make them a good candidate for being in the same aggregate with Product as a root. The module would then always be accessed via product, and if a module would have to be deleted from a product, the product would take care, since it is responsible for its lifecycle.
However UML does not impose anything on DDD. The guiding question is how to best keep consistency when it comes to changes, and how synchronous these changes should be.  If both entities are indeed very independent when it comes to change, you could perfectly decide to have each of them in its own aggregate.  It will work perfectly well, and the sole complexification would be the need for a domain service to ensure coordinated deletion of both a product and all its modules.
If however there is more interdependency between changes, and some consistency rules would need to be enforced,  you could still keep them in separate aggregates,  but you'd need domain events to maintain the objects in synch.  This can only be envisaged if the consistency rule does not to be immediate and if keeping the two entities in sync can be done asynchronously.

I have a bit of a write-up on this.  I can elaborate if that doesn't help.
The gist of it is that an Entity is typically also the aggregate root.  There may be instances where you need a different (synthetic) entity that acts as the aggregate root but I don't think that a "Software Product" with a collection of "Module" instances would need something like, if that truly is your domain.
Also, just to broaden the scope a bit here, keep in mind that an aggregate root should not contains instances of other aggregate roots, but rather either a collection of ids (of the related aggregate roots) or a collection of value objects representing the related aggregate roots.  Mentioning this in case your Module is perhaps an entity.
